# How to fire trigger after every insert in sql server table automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I am new to SQL Server triggers. I am facing a problem recently that I have two tables named `tbl_Item` and `tbl_changePrice`. I want to update `tbl_Item` when `tbl_changeprice` is inserted new row. With this new row name same date data will be updated in `tbl_item` table.

Here is my trigger what is tried by me for updating the table:

```
Alter TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[tbl_changePrice] 
After insert
AS
    declare @itemname int;
    declare @saleprice decimal(18,2);
    declare @buyprice decimal(18,2);

    select @itemname=i.name from inserted i;    
    select @saleprice=i.saleprice from inserted i;  
    select @buyprice=i.pprice from inserted i;  

    update tbl_Item set sellingPrice= @saleprice, buyingPrice= @buyprice where name= @itemname

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @itemname=i.name from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle **multiple rows** being inserted at once - you need to rewrite your trigger to be able to deal with **multiple rows** in `Inserted` - something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgAfterInsert 
ON [dbo].[tbl_changePrice] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.tbl_Item 
    SET sellingPrice = i.saleprice, buyingPrice = i.pprice 
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE tbl_Item.name = i.name

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```